# Showing context menu in controller

Tags: extjs

I have two `views` - one for tree panel and one for context menu (defined as `FilesEditor.view.FilesEditorContextMenu`). And I have a `controller`, in which it listens to `itemcontextmenu` event. I do not know how should I create (where and at what stage?) and how to show my `FilesEditorContextMenu`. The part of the listener looks like this:

```
itemcontextmenu:function(view, rec, item, index, event){
    event.stopEvent();
    ... What should I do next? How should I instantiate and show a context menu
}
```

**EDIT**

I investigated the code of this [example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/example/simple-tasks/index.html) which has similar functionality to what I want, but the problem is - I can't find the implementation of `getContextMenu()` - which is the most important in terms of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample code to open a context menu (This will give you some idea):

```
itemcontextmenu: function(view, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
        var position = e.getXY(),
            menu = Ext.create('FilesEditor.view.FilesEditorContextMenu', {
            id: 'myMenu',
            items: [{
                text: 'Some Menu Item',
                handler: function() {
                    // do your stuff
                }
            }],
            listeners: {
                mouseleave: function() {
                    // close menu
                    menu.close();// check documentation https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.menu.Menu-method-close
                }
            }
        });
        e.stopEvent(); // prevent the browser default context menu
        menu.refView = view; // passing the view reference to the menu so that we can get a handle of the grid inside the menu item handler
        menu.showAt(position);
    }
```

Comment: I wonder whether this approach will lead to memory leak or not. Since every time when a user right clicks, a new instance of context menu is created. Is it possible to create it once, and re-use it after?

Comment: You'll close the menu when you leave it. Check updated answer.